# datetime field default gets truncated

Tags: 8

I have a datetime field on a custom entity defined in baseFieldDefinitions().
This has set a default, which should be now.
But when saving the entity, i get following error:

> Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'date' at row 1: INSERT INTO {sale} (uuid, langcode, user_id, name, status, created, changed, date, price, party) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 3e25c5cb-0092-42dd-914b-4e4b91bdcf19 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => en [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => Jupiler [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 1516504047 [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 1516504047 [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => 2018-01-21 04:07:06 Europe/Brussels [:db_insert_placeholder_8] => 2 [:db_insert_placeholder_9] => 1 ) in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->doSaveFieldItems() (line 878 of /var/www/drupalvm/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).

This is my field definition:

```
$fields['date'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('datetime')
  ->setLabel(t('Sale date'))
  ->setDescription(t('The date that the sale took place.'))
  ->setRequired(true)
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
    'label' => 'above',
    'type' => 'string',
    'weight' => -4,
  ))
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
    'type' => 'date',
    'weight' => -4,
  ))
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
  ->setDefaultValue(DrupalDateTime::createFromTimestamp(time()));
```

How are datetime fields supposed to get a default value?
If you look at the error, the value it tries to save is '2018-01-21 04:07:06 Europe/Brussels'.

Answer (score 1):

As the BaseFieldDefenitions are cached, this won't work I believe.

I think you would be better off by using SetDefaultValueCallback:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21BaseFieldDefinition.php/function/BaseFieldDefinition%3A%3AsetDefaultValueCallback/8.2.x

Comment: well, it actually tries to save a date if you look at the error:
    Data too long for column 'date' at row 1 ... [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => 2018-01-21 04:07:06 Europe/Brussels ...

Comment: you could use the correct date format `DATETIME_DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT`, but this answer is about the main problem here, that you store the default date when the entity field definitions are rebuilt/cached and not when the entity is saved.